# wrapping regex.h with python ctypes

Tags: python, c, regex, ctypes

I am trying to write a python wrapper using ctypes for the standard c library's regex functionality (no I don't wan't to just use pythons re module).

I am stuck on how to wrap specifically the re_pattern_buffer structure in regex.h.  Here is the piece of code I'm concerned with:

```
struct re_pattern_buffer
{
/* Space that holds the compiled pattern.  It is declared as
   'unsigned char *' because its elements are sometimes used as
   array indexes.  */
unsigned char *__REPB_PREFIX(buffer);

/* Number of bytes to which `buffer' points.  */
unsigned long int __REPB_PREFIX(allocated);

/* Number of bytes actually used in `buffer'.  */
unsigned long int __REPB_PREFIX(used);

/* Syntax setting with which the pattern was compiled.  */
reg_syntax_t __REPB_PREFIX(syntax);

/* Pointer to a fastmap, if any, otherwise zero.  re_search uses the
   fastmap, if there is one, to skip over impossible starting points
   for matches.  */
char *__REPB_PREFIX(fastmap);

/* Either a translate table to apply to all characters before
   comparing them, or zero for no translation.  The translation is
   applied to a pattern when it is compiled and to a string when it
   is matched.  */
__RE_TRANSLATE_TYPE __REPB_PREFIX(translate);

/* Number of subexpressions found by the compiler.  */
size_t re_nsub;
```

Here's my attempt so far at wrapping this structure using ctypes:

```
reg_syntax_t = ctypes.c_ulong # unsigned long int
class regex_t(ctypes.Structure): # AKA: re_pattern_buffer
    _fields_ = [
                ("a", ctypes.c_void_p), # unsigned char *__REPB_PREFIX(buffer);
                ("b", ctypes.c_ulong),  # unsigned long int __REPB_PREFIX(allocated);
                ("c", ctypes.c_ulong),  # unsigned long int __REPB_PREFIX(used);
                ("d", reg_syntax_t),     # reg_syntax_t __REPB_PREFIX(syntax);
                ("e", ctypes.c_ubyte),  # char *__REPB_PREFIX(fastmap);
                ("re_nsub", ctypes.c_size_t),
               ]
```

I believe I am getting seg faults due to some error in here.

What is going on with __REPB_PREFIX(...) in C?  How should I represent this using pythons ctypes?

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Sorry for being a pain but I've got to ask. Re `I don't want to just use Python's re module`, why not?

Comment: Indeed. `re` just hands off everything possible to `_sre`, so you're gaining little if anything.

Comment: Because this is for an application where I need *exactly* posix syntax, so no re

Comment: `buffer`, `fastmap`, and `translate` (missing) should be `c_char_p`. [`reg_syntax_t`](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/posix/regex.h?v=glibc-2.13#0039) should be defined as `c_ulong`. Ignore `__REPB_PREFIX`; this macro adds a prefix at the API level, which is unrelated to the struct ABI.